# ¿Como puedo capturar la cantidad de veces que le dan click a un botón?

Tags: java, android

Deseo realizar un evento cuando le dan click a un botón, como si quedara check, y realizar otro cuando le da nuevamente a ese botón.

Comment: ¿Qué hemos intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: El título de la pregunta y el contenido parecen diferentes. ¿Necesitas saber la cantidad exacta de veces que le dan clic, o sólo darle al botón un estado como "cliqueado/descliqueado"?

Comment: @RodrigoSalgadoAtala cliqueado/descliqueado

Comment: Podrías heredar de la clase `Button` y agregarle un `boolean checked = false` y sobreescribir el onClick, alternando la variable booleana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proba esto:

```
public class DoubleclickActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private boolean cliqueado = false;
  private int conteo_clicks = 0;

  nombre_boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
     if(!cliqueado){
       System.out.println("primer click del boton");
       cliqueado = true;
     } else { 
       System.out.println("Segundo click del boton");
       cliqueado = false;
     }
     conteo_clicks++;
   }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

de esta manera

```
int click;

nombre_boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {  
       click =click+1; 
       // puede ser click++;
   }
}
```